Early 2000’s horror movie about an evil man and the water which people go into and come out either evil or dead
I want to say this movie was made in the early 2000’s, I remember watching it when I was maybe 11 or 12 on the SyFy channel during October. 
It starts off with two boys playing near water and they walk through the water to what I feel like was an abandon jail or just an abandon white brick like building. They go inside and find a creepy older man and i don’t recall exactly if one of the boys dies or not. 
Then the movie skips forward many years and what I can remember is that a woman is babysitting a little boy and he has a paper airplane that he keeps throwing in front of him over and over again until he reaches the edge of the water (this whole movie is mainly around the lake in whatever town they live in and I think they maybe have accents or something) the babysitter runs up behind him and tells him to come back inside. 
There’s also a scene where a woman is laying by the water and I believe her boyfriend died or she thought he did, but he comes out of the water but he’s like half dead and starts killing her, I think. Please don’t let the last clue throw you off because I’m not exactly sure. 
The water is evil or something and the creepy older man is also a bigger part of the movie, once people enter the water, something takes them and turns them evil or dead (zombie?). I really can’t remember, sorry!!

18, but i’m also not 100% on the age i was when i watched it but it was somewhere around there and i doubt the movie came out the year i watched it, so i’m assuming early 2000’s?

nooo, i didn’t watch it when it had just come out is what i’m saying. it was probably at least a couple years old when i watched it. it could have come out 10 years before i saw it for all i know. sorry for the confusion.

does it sound familiar to you at all?? i’ve been looking everywhere for this movie and nothing i search will give me the movie. it’ll advert me to shark movies or zombie movies.

Sounds like the horror film Beneath Still Waters from 2005.

In 1965, in Northern Spain, a dam will be built to bring progress to the location of Desbaria and the town of Marienbad is near to be completely flooded. Two boys, Teo and Luis, cross the security boundary to play in the evacuated town and Teo listen to voices in the abandoned church. They find a group of strange people chained in the watered basement, Teo releases their leader Mordecai Salas and is killed by him. Forty years later, in the celebration of the fortieth anniversary of Debaria Dam, the teenager Antonio vanishes in the lake while swimming with his girlfriend Susana and their friend Clara Borgia. The police divers, with the support of the outsider cameraman journalist Dan Quarry that is filming the submerged Marienbad to write a matter about the town, try unsuccessfully to find the body. When eerie things happen in the spot, Dan and the local journalist and daughter of the builder of the dam Teresa Borgia disclose dark secrets about Marienbad, Salas and his evil cult of the power of the flame.

It starts like you described, the water is evil and conjures the corpses of loved ones that draw people in, there's a boy playing with a white styrofoam glider who is drawn into the water but is pulled back by his babysitter (who's a main character), the creepy man living near it, it's all there. The movie also aired on Syfy (then Sci-Fi) in October 2009. Here's the trailer:




oh my god, you are amazing! you have no idea how many years i’ve been trying to figure this out. thank you so much!

@Alyssa No problem! :) Don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark next to it, this effectively resolves your question. And welcome to M&TV!
